# Connecting to Microsoft SQL Server in Python

Tags: python, sql-server, driver, windows-authentication, tableau-desktop

I'm currently running into the issue of being unable to connect to the a microsoft sql server database through python that I can connect to via Tableau. I'm attempting to track some historical data that we cannot keep within our database for future years. This uses windows authentication and I've confirmed it working from my local machine to the server in Tableau. However, I'm not sure what driver Tableau uses in order to make this connection. I have tried to connect via ODBC in Tableau and run into the same issue as I do in python.

```
   import pyodbc
   cnxn_write = pyodbc.connect(driver='{SQL Server}',
                            server='FQDN, Port Number\SQLEXPRESS',
                            database='DataAnalytics',
                            trusted_connection='yes'
                           )
```

Returns the following error code

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OperationalError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_6969/555555555.py in <module>
      3 import pyodbc
      4 import date
time
----> 5 cnxn_write = pyodbc.connect(driver='{SQL Server}',
      6                             server='server-name\SQLEXPRESS',
      7                             database='DataAnalytics',

OperationalError: ('HYT00', '[HYT00] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Login timeout expired (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

The following code returns the same error.,

```
    import pyodbc
    cnxn_write = pyodbc.connect(driver='{SQL Server}',
                            server='FQDN, Port Number',
                            database='DataAnalytics',
                            trusted_connection='yes'
                           )
```

Anyone have any thoughts on what driver I should be using to attempt to connect with this database? I've tried {SQL Server} and {ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}. Or is this more likely to be on the server side than on my end?

Thanks everyone!

Comment: It's likely you aren't making a connection to the sql server. Are you certain you have the FQDN/IP correct? Is the port open between your computer running python and SQL Server?

Comment: Yes the FQDN is correct as I'm using the same one to connect via the Microsoft SQL Server option in Tableau. I would also assume that this implies the port is open between my computer and the SQL Server. However, when I go back to Python I simply timeout. That's why I think it's the driver, but I'm not 100% sure on that fact.

Comment: There's no port number in your connection string, only the instance name `\SQLEXPRESS`. Instance name resolution requires that the SQL Browser service is running and accessible via udp/1434, so you need to allow firewall access for both udp/1434 as well as your instance's tcp port for this to work. If you've already configured a port on your NAT/router to access your SQL server instance, such as tcp port 1433, then use that in the connection string instead, e.g.: `FullyQualifiedServerNameOrIpAddress,1433`.

Comment: I now have my script updated with the FQDN and port number statements noted above. I have confirmed the port number that I have with my IT department and am still running into this issue. Any other potential thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in case anyone else runs into this issue in the future. pyodbc was not properly connecting to the driver ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server. My fix was creating a User DSN after running the Windows executable odbcad32.exe. That properly identified the server, credentials and mirror server for the database. I called this User DSN 'sqlexpress' and the following is my connect string now.

```
cnxn_write = pyodbc.connect(r'DSN=sqlexpress')
```

Sadly this feels more like a workaround than a solution, but it now properly connects to my database.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but this worked for me. I use mssql

```
import pymssql  
conn = pymssql.connect(server='host:port', user='user', password='pass', database ='database')
```

#%%

```
cursor = conn.cursor()  
cursor.execute('SELECT TOP 10 * from table;')  
row = cursor.fetchone()  
while row:  
    print(str(row[0]) + " " + str(row[1]) + " " + str(row[2]))     
    row = cursor.fetchone()
```

Answer (score 0):

I also used' pyodbc' and worked both with Python and Python in Tableau. As you get a timeout error on login, I think the problem could be that you are not specifying the credentials to use in the connection string.

Try this

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd

server = 'your_server' 
database = 'your_database' 
username = 'your_username' 
password = 'your_password' 
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
```

**Query 1**

```
#Sample select query number 1
cursor.execute("SELECT @@version;") 
row = cursor.fetchone() 
while row: 
    print(row[0])
    row = cursor.fetchone()
```

**Query 2**

```
#Sample select query number 2
sql='''SELECT [RECORDID],[USERID],[COMMENT] FROM [dbo].[MyTable];'''
data = pd.read_sql(sql,cnxn)

data.head()
```

Does it works for you?