# Connecting to Microsoft SQL Server with Python using a smart card

Tags: python, sql-server, smartcard

For me as a GNU/Linux (Debian 11 Bullseye) power user, it is quite a simple task to [connect to a Microsoft SQL Server using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71162582/3375584) with its [pyodbc](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Getting-started) module. Unfortunately, my organization requires **smart card** authentication for this to accomplish. Is there any information out there for how to do that??

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm also having trouble with mssql and smart cards, but even on Windows. Wondering if there's some common simple thing being missed.

Comment: I'm afraid I still have no solution. Therefore, I will need to humbly beg my DBA for an dedicated account.—Do you have an approach for connecting using smart card on Windows?

Comment: It's bizarre. It doesn't happen for all users, and I can't for the life of me figure out what's different about them vs the ones that do work. I also have a user who, if she ever logs on with her password because she forgot her smart card, it breaks everything to do with Office 365 and Azure AD for her, to the point her local profile just has to be blown away.